# _.get does not work with module.exports object

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have a node file that exports an object

> **(path './../../config/cloud.js):**

```
module.exports = {
   some: {
       property: 1
   }
}
```

if I use the following code:

```
const config   = require('./../../config/cloud');
const _  = require('lodash');
console.log(_.get(config, 'some.property'); // prints undefined
console.log(config.some.property); // print 1
```

*Can you help me to see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks*

EDIT: I expect that the first `console.log` prints `1` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: @Kalariya_M the first `console.log` should print `1`. Or at least is what I'm expect.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: ('./../../config/cloud.js') try this i think the variable config can't load file also try printing config var

Comment: @Kalariya_M config var prints as  `{some: {property: 1}}`. That's also why the second console.log works.

Comment: @Simoyw is this really the _exact_ code that you're using?

Comment: @robertklep all right so seems to be a problem on my setup...but really strange...

Comment: @Simoyw there are a few reasons why this may happen, although it would also mean that the second `console.log` (if run directly after the first `console.log`) would fail: `module.exports` is being set in an async function, or there's a cycling dependency (where your main file loads `cloud.js` which in turn loads your main file; this doesn't have to be directly but could also happen through an intermediary file that they both load)

Comment: @robertklep the config file does not load/require anything. I will re-check the code.

Comment: @robertklep @Kalariya_M I've found the problem. I looked endpoints response message where this code is called I get an error `can not call get of undefined`. So for some reason, this error was not present in my logs and I only saw the undefined print. I anyways cannot see why the _ variable is undefined but I will probably find the problem now that I know where to investigate...thanks a lot for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `_` was undefined and was throwing an exception that was not visible in my logs somehow.